# Is a simple curve which is nulhomotopic the boundary of a surface?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Let $C$ be a simple curve in  an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^3$. Suppose that $C$ is nulhomotopic in $U$. Must there exist a homeomorphism $f$ from the closed unit disk $D$ in $\mathbb R^2$ to $U$ such that $f(\partial D) = C$?

This seems intuitively like it should be true, and I believe I have seen a statement of this sort somewhere. I tried proving it myself by approximating a homotopy by an injective map, but was not successful. I would be fine with a reference to a statement which implies this one, or the proof itself (or a counterexample in case it is not true).

Comment: Can you not just look at the disk swept out by the circle as it shrinks to a point and map $D$ to that in the obvious way?

Comment: If U is planar, or homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ , then the answer is yes, by Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: @DanielRust We don't necessarily know that a homotopy from $C$ to a point is injective.

Comment: @user99680 $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$, so by invariance of domain it cannot be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider a knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The knot is nullhomotopic, since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is contractible. Suppose the knot bounded an embedded disk. Such a disk is a genus-zero Seifert surface for the knot, so the knot is the unknot. Therefore nontrivial knots in $\mathbb{R}^3$ do not bound embedded disks.

(c.f. page 2 of this: http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~mgscharl/papers/knottheory.pdf)

Comment: But can an unknot be homotopically-trivial?

Comment: @user99680 Absolutely. In fact, every map into a contractible space is homotopically trivial so all knots (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) are nullhomotopic.

Comment: I should have noticed this earlier :) Good answer.