# Is a sufficiently nice simple curve which is nulhomotopic the boundary of a surface?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

This is a follow up to [Is a simple curve which is nulhomotopic the boundary of a surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676939/is-a-simple-curve-which-is-nulhomotopic-the-boundary-of-a-surface). There, I asked whether, given a simple curve $C$ in an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^3$ which is nulhomotopic in $U$, there exists a homeomorphism $f$ from the closed unit disk $D$ in $\mathbb R^2$ to $U$ such that $f(\partial D) = C$. The answer to that question is "no", as the curve $C$ might be a complicated knot which cannot bound a surface.

I am wondering if a slight refinement of the above question might be true, namely suppose that $C$ is a simple curve in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $C = \partial S$ for some surface $S$ in $\mathbb R^3$ homeomorphic to a disk. If $C$ is nulhomotopic in an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^3$, must there exist a homeomorphism $f$ from the closed unit disk $D$ in $\mathbb R^2$ to $U$ such that $f(\partial D) = C$?

I don't mind additional regularity assumptions on $C$ (we can even require $C$ to be a circle if needed) but I would like to see an answer which treats a fairly general $U$.

Comment: This can be proven using the "loop theorem", following some standard 3d topology arguments. Details are a bit long.

Comment: @studiosus Do you have a reference?

Comment: Not for the claim itself. But it's proof can be reduced to the case when the loop lies on the boundary of your domain and then it is an application of the "Dehn lemma" (check Wikipedia page to find out what it is).

Comment: By $\partial S$, do you mean the image of $\partial D$ under the assumed homeomorphism into $\mathbb{R}^3$? So the issue is whether we can replace this homeomorphism with one mapping in $U$, such that it maps $\partial D$ to the same subset of $S$?

Comment: @MichaelWeiss yes, this is correct.